# Cancel the alertview's function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

in my app there is two scenes. in first view controller i used a uialertview, it will popup after 30 seconds. if i move to next scene before 30 seconds means , the first scene's UiAlertview should not  popup .

Comment: Can you share any code? What is your specific question?

Comment: You are not asking for a coding question to solve here. You need some code, or some specific coding question.

Comment: before moving to next scene, is it possible to cancel uialertview's process. can u get me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a timer, and when the the view you are on dissapears, cancel the timer:

```
   self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(showPopUp)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
```

And then:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.myTimer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: tanQ for ur's quick reply
 @Antonio, its working!!

Answer (score 0):

take a Timer variable as global

```
NSTimer *Timer;

Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)showAlert
{
   //show your alert view;
}
```

use `viewWillDisappear` method to disable your timer to prevent not to show the alert while you are in next viewcontroller

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [Timer invalidate];
}
```